# I made a program for the 99 bottles song, but it doesn't print the song correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def printLyrics(beer):
    print(str(beer) + " bottles of beer on the wall, " + str(beer) + " bottles of beer")
    print("Take one down and pass it around " + str(beer-1)  + " bottles of beer on the wall.")
    print()


    if beer == 2:
        print("2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.")
        print("Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.")
        print()    
    elif beer == 1:
        print("1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.")
        print("Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.")
        print()
```

This line prints every time bottles on the wall runs, I don't know how to fix it.
else:
print("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.")
print("Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.")
print()

def main():
for beer in range(99,0,-1):
printLyrics(beer)

main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking the same thing as Alain.

```
def print_lyrics(beer):
    if beer == 2:
        print("2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.")
        print("Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.")
        print()    
    elif beer == 1:
        print("1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.")
        print("Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.")
        print()
    elif beer == 0:
        print("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.")
        print("Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.")
        print()
    else:
        print(str(beer) + " bottles of beer on the wall, " + str(beer) + " bottles of beer")
        print("Take one down and pass it around " + str(beer-1)  + " bottles of beer on the wall.")
        print()


for beer in range(99, -1, -1):
    print_lyrics(beer)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first set of prints should be conditional to beer > 2.

```
def printLyrics(beer):
    if beer>2:
        print(str(beer) + " bottles of beer on the wall, " + str(beer) + " bottles of beer")
        print("Take one down and pass it around " + str(beer-1)  + " bottles of beer on the wall.")
        print()
    elif beer == 2:
        print("2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.")
        print("Take one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.")
        print()    
    else:
        print("1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.")
        print("Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.")
        print()

for beer in range(99,0,-1):
    printLyrics(beer)
```